# What is efficient way of removing empty values from dict inside list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is efficient way of removing empty values from dictionary which is saved inside the list.

```
list1 = [{'l1k1': 'l1v1', 'l1k2': 'l1v2'}, {'l2k1': 'l2v1', 'l2k2': ''}]
list2 = []
for l in list1:
  d = {}
  for k, v in l.items():
    if v.strip() is not None or v.strip() != '':
      d[k] = v
  list2.append(d)
print(list2)
```

Actual Output:

```
[{'l1k1': 'l1v1', 'l1k2': 'l1v2'}, {'l2k1': 'l2v1', 'l2k2': ''}]
```

Expected Output:

```
[{'l1k1': 'l1v1', 'l1k2': 'l1v2'}, {'l2k1': 'l2v1'}]
```

Comment: picky, but in your example you actually do not remove the key/value pairs, you just don't copy them

Comment: Suppose v is an empty string. In that case (v.strip() is not None) will be True, so the empty string is added to the dict d anyway due to the 'or' condition. Reasoning about combining negatives (is not and !=) is hard and I'd recommend avoiding it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
list1 = [{'l1k1': 'l1v1', 'l1k2': 'l1v2'}, {'l2k1': 'l2v1', 'l2k2': ''}]
list2 = [{ k: v for k, v in d.items() if v and v.strip() } for d in list1]
```

Notice that the *correct* check to do here is `v and v.strip()`, that ensures that the string is not `None` and is not all spaces. It works as expected:

```
list2
=> [{'l1k1': 'l1v1', 'l1k2': 'l1v2'}, {'l2k1': 'l2v1'}]
```

It's efficient because it uses list comprehensions and dictionary comprehensions, which are faster than doing explicit loops. Also, it's quite compact and idiomatic :)

Comment: I do not know, I am getting same result, list1 = [{'l1k1': 'l1v1', 'l1k2': 'l1v2'}, {'l2k1': 'l2v1', 'l2k2': ''}]
list2 = [ { k: v for k, v in d.items() } for d in list1]
print(list2)
print(list1)

Comment: Sometimes i get this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: @Pallaveera that means that some of your dicts have values that are dicts themselves! Check your input data, it doesn't look like the one in the question.

Answer (score 8):

Try this :

```
list2 = [{k:v for k,v in i.items() if v!= '' or v.strip() != ''} for i in list1]
```

We can use dict-comprehension as well as list-comprehension simultaneously. We loop for every element (which is a dictionary) of `list1`, and just take those key-value pairs where the value or `value.strip()` for the corresponding key in the dictionary is not a vacant string.

A shorter version for cancelling the values with `None` type also:

```
list2 = [{k:v for k,v in i.items() if v} for i in list1]
```

Comment: this is good but you should probably explain a little what it does, comprehensions aren't the most obvious things to new comers

Comment: This is too verbose (not to mention mistaken, because of the `or`), and also it's not handling the `None` case. Check my answer for a simpler solution.

Comment: The `strip()` part in this code is useless, because you're using `or`. If `v=' '` then `v!='' or v.strip()!=''` is true.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple alternative, not using list comprehension that may be easier for you to follow:

```
for d in list1:
  for k in d.keys():
      if d[k] != '':
          list2.append({k:d[k]})
```

Answer (score 0):

making a copy of your list is not very efficient, unless you WANT to keep the original as well. you can just remove the entries that are "empty" like so:

```
list1 = [{'l1k1': 'l1v1', 'l1k2': 'l1v2'}, {'l2k1': 'l2v1', 'l2k2': ''}]
for item in list1:
    for key in list(item.keys()):
        if not item[key].strip():
            del item[key]
```

this part `list(item.keys())` is important. why list? because python doesnt like it when you change the size the dict during iteration, if we pre-get the keys, we will be iterating on a list instead of a generator.

`not item[key].strip()` is also a good to note, empty strings evaluate to `False` while non-empty string evaluate to `True`

*note: strictly speaking the `.keys()` isnt necessary, but it does help readability if youre new to python

Answer (score 0):

```py
list1 = [{'l1k1': 'l1v1', 'l1k2': 'l1v2'}, {'l2k1': 'l2v1', 'l2k2': ''}]
```

The most efficient way is this:

```
list2 = [{k: v for k,v in dic.items() if v} for dic in list1]
```

PS:

using `.strip()` works for strings only and since you have all types of `False`/`None`/`""` values those would not be removed, infact you would get bugs. Also: using `.strip()` just to remove `" "` (with a space) is wrong since `" "` is not even a `False` value in Python and you really should not consider it as such also. To remove certain characters (other than empty ones as in your question) you should try to create and use a different specific function instead that does just that.